# How to run webdriverio tests on firefox using wdio testRunner and wdio-selenium-standalone-service

Tags: firefox, webdriver-io

My environment:

1. Mac OSX 10.12.6
2. webdriverio(using the test runner i.e., wdio)(`"webdriverio": "^4.9.11"`)
3. Cucumber framework (`"wdio-cucumber-framework": "^1.0.3"`)
4. Using `WDIO Selenium Standalone Service` help to start the selenium service automatically.(`"wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.10"`)
5. firefox(version: 52)

I am able to successfully run the tests on chrome browser(version: 65) but when it comes to firefox i always get `connection refused` error.

More details:

In the wdio config file i have mentioned `firefox` as browserName. Once the test is started firefox launches and it stays on the "New Tab" page. It does not navigate to the URL.

After some time(like: 60 secs later), In the wdio logs i can see `ERROR: connection refused`. Additionally the firefox also does not quit in the end.

NOTE: The same test works fine if change the `browserName` to `chrome`.

WDIO Config file capabilities part:

```
...capabilities: [{

    maxInstances: 5,
    //
    browserName: 'firefox',
    marionette: true,
}],...
```

Answer (score 4):

Able to FIX the issue by myself after some research.

The problem is version mismatch.

The geckoDriver verison is `0.20.0` and the firefox version i was using is `52`.

I upgraded the firefox to latest. i.e., version `59` and i was able to successfully run the test.

As per geckoDriver release notes of version `0.19.0`

```
Note that with geckodriver v0.19.0 the following versions are recommended:
Firefox 55.0 (and greater)
Selenium 3.5 (and greater)
```

So i understood that the higher version also should have the same property.