# Executing TestRunner on WebdriverIO fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

I'm following http://webdriver.io/guide.html guide. Executing TestRunner following the instructions on this page, doesn't seem to help.

Errors that I see:

```
PS C:\webdriverio-test> .\node_modules\.bin\wdio .\wdio.conf.js

ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
firefox
    at new RuntimeError (C:\webdriverio-test\node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\utils\ErrorHandler.js:144:12)
    at Request._callback (C:\webdriverio-test\node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\utils\RequestHandler.js:330:43)
    at self.callback (C:\webdriverio-test\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\webdriverio-test\node_modules\request\request.js:878:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

**wdio.conf.js file:**

```
exports.config = {

    specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    maxInstances: 10,

    capabilities: [{
        maxInstances: 5,
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }],

    sync: true,

    // Level of logging verbosity: silent | verbose | command | data | result | error
    logLevel: 'silent',

    coloredLogs: true,

    deprecationWarnings: true,

    bail: 0,

    screenshotPath: './errorShots/',

    baseUrl: 'http://<machine_ip_here>',

    waitforTimeout: 10000,

    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,

    connectionRetryCount: 3,

    framework: 'mocha',

    reporters: ['dot'],

    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd'
    },
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Please see this answer below and try whether this helps:

Able to FIX the issue by myself after some research.

The problem is version mismatch.

The geckoDriver verison is 0.20.0 and the firefox version i was using is 52.

I upgraded the firefox to latest. i.e., version 59 and i was able to successfully run the test.

As per geckoDriver release notes of version 0.19.0

```
Note that with geckodriver v0.19.0 the following versions are recommended:
Firefox 55.0 (and greater)
Selenium 3.5 (and greater)
So i understood that the higher version also should have the same property.
```

[How to run webdriverio tests on firefox using wdio testRunner and wdio-selenium-standalone-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987451/how-to-run-webdriverio-tests-on-firefox-using-wdio-testrunner-and-wdio-selenium)

Thanks, Naveen